# По какой причине не отображается карта в Leaflet, несмотря на правильный путь расположения плиток карт?

Tags: django, карты

Путь D:\PL\newproject\blog\static\blog\here.com.terrain

```
{% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <title>Test Map</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'blog/leafletnew/leaflet.css' %}>
            <script src={% static 'blog/leafletnew/leaflet.js'%}></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id='map' style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
            </div>
            <script>
                const map = L.map('map',{   
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3396,
                        animate: true,
                        fullscreenControl: false,
                });
                L.tileLayer('/blog/here.com.terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    minZoom: 0,
                    maxZoom: 13,
                    attribution: 'NokiaMaps'
                }).addTo(map);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image: Проблема]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

При инициализации карты её необходимо центрировать, чтобы было от чего ориентироваться. `center: [широта, долгота]`, необходимо добавить в

```
const map = L.map('map',{   
      crs: L.CRS.EPSG3396,
      animate: true,
      fullscreenControl: false
});
```